# How do you build a distribution file in windows

Tags: python-3.x

The book I am following appears to be based on linux and points to create a setup file called stup.py as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name         = 'some_program',
    version      = '12.43',
    py_modules   = ['some_program'],
    author       = 'xyz',
    author_email = 'xyz@gmail.com'
    url          = 'http://example.com'
    description  = 'A simple python function'
    )
```

Then, it says to enter:  `stup.py sdist` *on the terminal* and install it using `sudo python3 stup.py install`, however, I'm on windows, I don't know if we are supposed to do something from the command prompt, how do we do the equivalent procedure in windows?

Comment: replace `terminal` with `command prompt` or `cmd`, and you should be good to go

Comment: Also, you don't need `sudo` if you installed the Python interpreter for the current user. If not, use a `virtualenv`. (If strictly required, `runas` does a similar thing.)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget , it doesn't work, it says python3 is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: then you need to figure out where you've installed python on your machine and run the relevant exe